"Unable to negotiate a key exchange method" error only when I SSH via "Screen"
I need to SSH to a local host after making a screen session. I can SSH to the host without the screen but when I do it within the screen is gives error, "Unable to negotiate a key exchange method".
I have searched online for this but I have not found a suitable answer. Also, the server that I am using is a shared server so I can not make too many changes to its settings.

This question lacks any usable info. Please read over the info on this link, after doing that please edit the question and add some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Use ssh -v ... to find out what's going on
